# Does new Windows netsh firewall rule break existing connection?

Tags: firewall, windows-firewall, netsh

Can't find the answer anywhere and I'm a little bit afraid to check this out on my computer.

I want to block all traffic that comes from specific address - except one, which is already established.

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=”ping” protocol=icmpv4 action=block 
dir=in remoteip=xxx.xxx.xx.xx
```

Is it okay to add new netsh advfirewall rule that block all the traffic from the address or it'll break my existing connection too?